# SQL - Join Three Tables with common link in third table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, join

Before I begin, Yes, I thoroughly tried searching for many tutorials on JOINS/INNER JOINS/OUTER JOINS/FULL JOINS but I'm not exactly sure *what* I'm looking for so a little guidance or simply a finger pointing me in the correct direction would be very helpful. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

So basically, I have Three tables

Foo

```
| FooID | name | data  |
  1      Name1  Data1
  2      Name2  Data2
  3      Name3  Data3
  4      Name4  Data4
```

Bar

```
| BarID |
 1
 2
```

Matrix

```
| BarID | FooID|
 1        2
 1        3
 1        4
 2        1
 2        3
```

So what I'm looking for is, I basically have **BarID** (let's just pretend it's **1** for clarity purposes). I want to get all the rows from table **Matrix** that correlate to **BarID**, so that way I can retrieve the rows that it relate to in Foo (For example, **BarID** = 1, so I should get rows 2, 3 and 4 in **Foo** and if BarID is 2, I will get 1 and 3, and so on).

I was trying something similar to:

```
SELECT Foo.FooID, Foo.name, Foo.data
FROM Bar
JOIN Matrix ON Matrix.BarID = 1     // The 1 is passed in, in this example
JOIN Foo ...                       // And this is where I'm stuck
```

Does this make sense what I'm trying to accomplish? I know it's weird. Will appreciate any assistance pointing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how joins work.  You normally `JOIN` tables among them `ON` related fields/columns that link together related data coming from those separate tables.  Then, you optionally use `WHERE` with whatever conditions (such as BarID = 1) to limit which of that data to `SELECT`.

Comment: @tonypdmtr Thank you.. You do realize that the question was already answered, correct? SQL is a language I started learning _today_ so sorry if I haven't learned everything in it's entirety. There are ways offering advice/help without being condescending. Obviously I have a misunderstanding, that's the _entire_ reason I'm on stackoverflow asking a question.

Comment: Well, then, you completely misunderstood my comment :)

Comment: @tonypdmtr I understood your comment just fine, and I appreciate the advice. But you don't get bonus points for trying to belittle me _before_ offering said advice. As I said, I appreciate the information, thank you, I will take that into consideration as I continue learning it.

Comment: Let me try again.  My comment was not to provide an answer as obviously you got your answer.  But the answer simply gave you what works, not what was wrong in your attempt.  My comment was to help you better understand the difference between `JOIN` and `WHERE`.  Now, you make me wonder: Why bother in the first place?  Good luck.

Comment: @tonypdmtr "Why bother in the first place?" Because if you had read the accepted answer and the resulting comment, I had already stated that I see where I went wrong and it helped me understand `JOIN` and `WHERE`. Again, if you read what I'm actually saying to you, my problem *isn't* with the advice itself. The advice was helpful, as I've been learning SQL for about 2 hours; this information gives even more clarity. My issue is the common theme I see on here a lot where you need to preface it with a comment that can be construed as condescending. It's not hard to be polite.

Comment: "My issue is the common theme I see on here a lot" reminded me of this joke where the husband calls his wife who's out driving to warn her about a car going down the wrong direction on that same highway she's on, only to hear his wife say: "It's not just one car, they are all going the wrong way!"  :) Lighten up.  People offering you help do not want to belittle you, or offend you in any way.  But, it is up to you to see it that way.  Signing off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a simple `JOIN` and `WHERE`

```
select f.*
from foo f join
     matrix m
     on f.fooid = m.fooid
where m.barid = 1;
```

You do not need the `bar` table, because you are passing in the id.  I think you might have been overthinking the problem.

Comment: Bingo! There it is. I knew I was thinking slightly too hard about it, looks like my thought process that was messing me up was that I needed the third table. Like I had the Matrix.BarID = 1 portion correct, and I knew that's where I needed it to go, I just didn't know how to format it properly. Thank you for the simple answer, that actually just helped me understand the JOIN/WHERE combination a bit better. I will mark this answer as accepted in 5 minutes when it lets me.